# what can cause asp.net site "service unavailable" from time to time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My site works well sometime, but after the recent update, the customer reported that it will be "service unavailable" from time to time.
I encountered this before, as I also upload the source .cs code and resource file to IIS, so if the .cs changes, the server will rebuild the application and in this time, every client request will be returned as "service unavailable".

But this time, not a fixed timing and action, server will turn to "service unavailable" from time to time when admin performs an action on web application, seems wenb site doesn't accept the request. We regard this as web-site server problem, but after the admin reboot the server, problem still existed.

So my question is, is anyone knows in what situation, asp.net site will go to "service unavailable" status?

Your suggestion will be very helpful to me. Thank you

Comment: See if there are any unhandled exceptions being logged in the Event Viewer on the server.

Comment: Do not deploy .cs files to production.  Pre-compile your site - use the appOffline.htm file if you are uploading changes to let people know that there might be a slight outage.  If you can't have any outage, then you might need to look at load balancing...

Comment: Normally if IIS reports "503 Service Unavailable" unexpectedly I'd think the app pool has crashed. Possibly from an infinite loop, or misbehaving application? I'd go with neoistheone's suggestion, look at the event logs and see if there's anything funny leading up to the issue.

Comment: @StevenV V Thanks for advise, you mentioned "Event Viewer", I'm using asp.net 2.0 for my website and seems no such thing for it. could you tell me where can I refer to this?

Comment: @StevenV the behaviour is same function, sometimes cause service unavailable, sometimes not, do not know how this happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above are good suggestions. I have also encountered situations where if you are allowing uploads via your web app and if those uploaded files are placed anywhere withing the directory structure of the web app itself on the server it causes IIS to recycle the app pool...which can cause the 503.

I resolved this by having the uploads place in folder outside of web application.

Comment: Thank you @JacobRutherford, that makes sense to me, I'll try your way and tell you the result. :)